# Одноразовое окно при первом запуске приложения

Tags: xcode, ios

Добрый день!

Не знаю, где еще можно задать этот вопрос, так что пишу на этом форуме.

В проекте в xcode нужно сделать так, чтобы при первом запуске приложения появлялось окно, о котором будет приветствие и базовые советы по работе, и чтобы после его закрытия оно больше никогда не появлялось. Но я совершенно не представляю, как это реализовать. Не могли бы вы дать ссылочку на какой-нибудь источник?

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Вам, как и просили, [ссылочка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664177/best-way-to-check-if-an-iphone-app-is-running-for-the-first-time). Но подтягивайте матчасть, на ссылочках далеко не уедете. И учтите, что за просьбы просто ссылок тут минусуют и правильно делают.